# How to write a same thread for common methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 methods that are running 2 tasks at same time. One of these tasks is common between threads, but I don't know how to write a unique method for the three tasks call it.

```
private void compare(String path) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do something
                finished = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(!finished){
                    statusLabel.setText("P-R-O-C-E-S-S-A-N-D-O");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    statusLabel.setText("");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                finished = false;
                statusLabel.setText("");
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}

private void sobeNovaBaseBlackList(String path){
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do another thing
            finished = true;
        }
    });


    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(!finished){
                    statusLabel.setText("P-R-O-C-E-S-S-A-N-D-O");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    statusLabel.setText("");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                finished = false;
                statusLabel.setText("");
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

private void sobeNovaBaseFornecedor(){
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do anything
            finished= true;
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while(!finished){
                    statusLabel.setText("P-R-O-C-E-S-S-A-N-D-O");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    statusLabel.setText("");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                finished = false;

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

As you can see,  thread 2 (t2) has the same behaviour in all the methods.  How to write t2 just one time?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that implements `Runnable` (ex: `class Task2 implements Runnable`) and write thread 2's code in run method. Then instantiate that in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Runnable interface and put your common code there. 
Something like:

```
public class ThreatT2 implements Runnable {
  private Boolean finished;

  public Test(Boolean finished) {
    this.finished = finished;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
      while(!finished){
        statusLabel.setText("P-R-O-C-E-S-S-A-N-D-O");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        statusLabel.setText("");
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
      finished = false;
      statusLabel.setText("");
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in you calling code you can invoke the run method

```
ThreatT2 t = new ThreatT2(true);
t.start();
```

Comment: ok, but how I should finish t2? I need when t1 finishes,  t2 finishes at the same time.

Comment: t1 and t2 and independent to each other so time guarantees are hard to get. If you want to block for both the threads to process before exiting the caller, try reading you can use `Joins` or `CountDownLatch `